# Google Smart Lock - When a Credential is save shouldn't we ask for Fingerprint or a device code just like iOS does with their KeyChain solution?

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

So maybe I'm wrong in assuming this but Google Smart Lock provides the same functionality as the iOS KeyChain solution, right (at least when it comes to saving passwords)?

Im seeing that iOS requires some sort of authentication every time we want to use a stored credential in the App but the Google Smart Lock just logs the user in without any extra authentication.

Could that be a security concern?

If my android device has no secure lock screen and there is an app that uses Smart Lock anybody that grabs my device would be able to login to the App.